# Constraint Programming Interview

Tags: constraint-programming

I'm new in CP. Want to start preparing for my upcoming interviews. What are the questions and topics should I study in CP to get my myself confident?

Comment: See this other question: [Constraint programming resources](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4672/constraint-programming-resources). (some good links in there!)

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming, one is also interested in what's happening internally aka "not only black-box view".*

I like the materials related to MiniCP, mostly:

- [Webpage | Link to Course materials](http://www.minicp.org/)
- [Paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12532-020-00190-7)

The papers abstract:

> This paper introduces MiniCP, a lightweight, open-source solver for constraint programming. MiniCP is motivated by educational purposes and, in particular, the desire to provide
> the core implementation of a constraint-programming solver for students in computer science and
> industrial engineering. The design of MiniCP provides a one-to-one mapping between the theoretical and implementation concepts and its compositional abstractions favor extensibility and
> flexibility. MiniCP obviously does not support all available constraint-programming features and
> implementation techniques, but these could be implemented as future extensions or exploratory
> projects. MiniCP also comes with a full set of exercises, unit tests, and development projects.

It seems to try to replicate what [Minisat](http://minisat.se/) did to the SAT-community:

> MiniSat
> has a neat, minimalist, and well-documented architecture that has enabled several generations
> of students and researchers to enter the field and make significant contributions

Those materials of course, have some bias towards some design-decisions which you will need to learn about from other sources if needed, an example:

- trail-based state-restoration (opposed to copy-based like gecode does)